# Left Outer Join with 2 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm having an issue with a postrgresql join. I might be approaching it incorrectly, but here's the scenario.

I have a table which contains two relevant columns: dates and months (along with other data). Each date should have the next 5 months associated with it, inclusive. This isn't always the case; I want to find when this isn't the case. Additionally, there is no guarantee that each date is in the table (for which there should be 5 months), but I have another table which contains these dates.

The table should contain (for one date):

[image: Expected]

However, due to many possibilities the table may only contain:

[image: Possible]

I have attempted to find the missing dates by generating a series for the expected dates and joining a series of months that should be associated with the date. I'm running into an issue because I need to join the tables on the two columns I need, so if one doesn't exist, it doesn't make it through the ON or WHERE clause.

I might need to approach this differently, but here is my current attempt.

```
SELECT 
    D.date, JOINMONTH::date, DT.month
FROM
    day D
CROSS JOIN
    generate_series(date_trunc('month', D.date),
                    date_trunc('month', D.date) + INTERVAL '4 months',
                    '1 month') AS JOINMONTH
LEFT JOIN 
    dates_table DT ON D.date = DT.date 
                   AND JOINMONTH::date = DT.month
WHERE
    D.date >= '2018-01-01';
```

What I would like to see:

[image: Result (goal)]

EDIT:
[This db-fiddle gives my full query.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7GqzziR9nanu3HhGgmk17s/0) I omitted some of the where clause because I thought it was irrelevant, but it seems to be part of the problem. With this in mind, my selected answer will solve my problem represented by this structure/query but @Gordon Linoff's answer is correct for the original question.

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. In a [mcve] format table initalizations as tables.

Comment: Hi. I'm going to try one more time re one thing... Please replace the images by code formatted as tables and put your DDL in your question--so we can understand & text search & also cut & paste & run without following a link. This should already be clear from what I wrote & from the MCVE link. PS If you want to change a question after reasonable answers are posted please post a new question--to avoid confusion including inappropriate answers & votes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT D.date, JOINMONTH::date, DT.month
FROM day D CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     generate_series(date_trunc('month', D.date),
                     date_trunc('month', D.date) + INTERVAL '4 months',
                     '1 month') AS JOINMONTH LEFT JOIN
     dates_table DT
     ON GD.date = DT.date AND JOINMONTH::date = DT.month
WHERE D.date >= '2018-01-01' AND DT.date IS NULL;
```

Comment: This did not solve my issue. The main difference between this and my attempt is the LATERAL and the DT.date IS NULL. The lateral doesn't change anything (as far as I'm aware - the CROSS JOIN returns the correct set of dates/months that I am testing for). Then again, the DT.date IS NULL won't help since the join is happening on JOINMONTH::date = MF.month and since MF.month wont ever equal the value I'm missing, I get no results.

Comment: @jlrosenberg . . . The `left join` should keep all the date combinations between `day` and `JOINMONTH`.  The `LEFT JOIN` and `WHERE` just filter out the ones that already exist.  The `LATERAL` is there just for correctness of the logic; this is a lateral join, not a `cross join`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Understood, thanks. However, the LEFT JOIN would keep the all date combinations if we were joining on one feild, but we are joining on two, one of which is the field I'm looking for when NULL. So we're testing for when DT.date IS NULL and when it IS NULL it will never be joined on the JOINMONTH series, since it doesn't have any NULLS.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for your help. I cant accept your answer because I have to update my question to include multiple details that weren't initially there - my fault.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT D.date, JOINMONTH::date, DT.month
FROM day D 
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     generate_series(date_trunc('month', D.date),
                     date_trunc('month', D.date) + INTERVAL '4 months',
                     '1 month') AS JOINMONTH 
LEFT JOIN dates_table DT
    ON D.date = DT.date 
    AND JOINMONTH::date = DT.month
    AND DT.source = 'S1' AND
    DT.tf = TRUE
WHERE 
    D.date = '2018-11-02';
```

I needed to move parts of my where clause into the join itself.